# TabView nested in TabView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, tabview

```
import SwiftUI

struct OrderPage: View {
    @State var tags = ["a", "b", "c", "d"] // Corrected with strings
    @State var currentIndex = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            OrderTagView(currentIndex: $currentIndex, tags: tags) // Corrected "tag" to "tags"
            TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
                InnerOrderPage().tag(0) // Corrected "InnderOrderPage" to "InnerOrderPage"
                InnerOrderPage().tag(1)
                InnerOrderPage().tag(2)
                InnerOrderPage().tag(3)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
}

struct InnerOrderPage: View { // Corrected the typo in struct name
    @State var tags = ["a", "b", "c", "d"] // Corrected with strings
    @State var currentIndex = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            OrderTagView(currentIndex: $currentIndex, tags: tags) // Corrected "tag" to "tags"
            TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
                Page().tag(0)
                Page().tag(1)
                Page().tag(2)
                Page().tag(3)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
}

struct Page: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Page Content")
    }
}

struct OrderTagView: View {
    @Binding var currentIndex: Int
    var tags: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(tags, id: \.self) { tag in
                Text(tag)
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(currentIndex == tags.firstIndex(of: tag) ? Color.blue : Color.gray)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        currentIndex = tags.firstIndex(of: tag) ?? 0
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my example code.

OrderTagView is a selected tag

When the InnerOrderPage within OrderPage is switched multiple times, clicking the OrderTagView inside the InnerOrderPage becomes ineffective, and Page() within the InnerOrderPage doesn't switch.

How to fix this issue